# Find and rename first result in linux?

Tags: linux, command-line, find, xargs

I have try using this commanline.

```
find *.txt | head -1 | xargs -0 mv *.txt test.txt
```

i receive.

> mv: target ‘02.txt\n’ is not a directory

What wrong :(?

Comment: Be aware of our sister site https://unix.stackexchange.com/ which answers questions on both Unix and Linux (all flavo(u)rs)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this instead:

```
find -name '*.txt' -print0 | head -z -1 | xargs -0 -I '{}' mv '{}' test.txt
```

What was wrong and why this should work instead:

- There's no point to using find if you're passing everything it should find anyway
- If you use null delimiters for anything in the pipeline, you need to use them for everything in the pipeline
- Your use of xargs wasn't substituting the `*.txt` for the name of the found file